# why use Gradle IntelliJ IDEA plugin?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

IntelliJ seems to support opening Gradle projects quite well out of the box.  Is there any reason to use the [Gradle IDEA plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/idea_plugin.html)?  What are advantages/disadvantages of working with/without it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Depends on what you want to do.
You can e. g. use the idea plugin to add some non-standard configurations, to be added to IDEA, or add some generated source directories to idea and so on.
This all has also an effect when opening the project through IDEA.

We go even a step further and configure code style settings and other stuff in the files that you can generate with the idea plugins tasks and use the generation task to have all this generated.

Additionally for us the idea plugins tasks depend on various code generation tasks without which the code would not compile in idea. So for us, we call the idea task and then have a ready-made project file that can immediately used for working.

For simple projects without any special need, just opening the project with IJ should be sufficient.